# Proxy Setting with Wpad file for Apache HttpClient API

Tags: java, proxy, httpclient

I have `Wpad` file used for automatic proxy settings. How I can use this file in HttpClient API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your Wpad file, there would be proxy host and port. All you need to do is use them and set `httpParams`. eg:

```
HttpHost proxy = new HttpHost(<proxyHost>, <proxyPort>);
httpClient.getParams().setParameter(ConnRoutePNames.DEFAULT_PROXY, proxy);
```

Comment: after that, it gives an error "Authentication is needed", how authentication is processed?

Comment: httpclient.getCredentialsProvider().setCredentials(new AuthScope("PROXY HOST", port),new UsernamePasswordCredentials("username", "password"));